# How to set the value's font size in danielgindi / Charts?

Tags: swift, charts

my codes are like  the following:

```
func getLineChartDataSet() -> LineChartDataSet {
    ...
    set.valueFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize:30)
    set.valueTextColor = UIColor.green
    return set
}
```

`set.valueTextColor = UIColor.green` works, the value's color changed from gray to green.
but `set.valueFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize:30)` changes nothing
how to set the value's fontsize then?
and how to change the display position of the value, I hope it displays under the circle, while it displays above the circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set.valueFont is overrided by the data.setValueFont method

data.setValueFont(.systemFont(ofSize: 10, weight: .bold))